# What kind of RF connector is this?

Tags: connector

I have ZTE MF112 and Huawei E173 3G modems with this kind of connector on mainboard:

[image]

What I want to try is to hook up an external 1.8-2.4GHz to modem. It looks like U.FL male connector to me, but I am not sure.

Comment: Are you out of your mind? Uploading a 2 megapixel image where not even 10% is relevant! You're lucky Olin didn't pass by.

Comment: @stevenvh And you think merely cropping the picture will save it from Olin's wrath?

Comment: @W5VO - Yeah, that's unlikely :-), but I can't fix the sharpness

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a ITT Cannon MiniRF test connector (Part No. 120220-0180) or Hirose MS-156C Receptacle. These components provide a straight-through connection until a test probe is inserted in the hole at the top. Which end of the connection the test probe is connected to depends on which way around the connector is soldered onto the PCB, so that would determine whether it would be possible to connect an external antenna here. However these are not latching connectors (unlike the u.Fl mentioned above) so not ideal for a permanent connection. You might be able to solder on a u.Fl connector in its place though.

Comment: Does it work as antenna ? can i use it to connect external antennas ?

Answer (score 5):

Looks like Hirose UFL.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hirose_U.FL

[image]